# Python parsing using JSON for use with seleium

Tags: python, json, parsing, selenium, scripting

I'm trying to write a python script that will read in a JSON file with the aim to show how many screens are available and be able to pull the value of the different json fields

JSON

```
   {
    "screen": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "user": "user1@example.com",
        "password": "letmein",
        "code": "123456"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "user": "user2@example.com",
        "password": "letmein",
        "code": "123455"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "user": "user3@example.com",
        "password": "letmein",
        "code": "223456"
        }
    ]
}
```

Python

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('screen.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

#json_file.close()


pprint(data)

data["screen"][0]["id"]
```

As you can see from python script I can successfully print out the json file is pprint but when I try just find print out individual values I'm getting stuck

Am I doing something wrong here?

I want to be able to use all the values in json files as variables later on in python script to be able to be used with selenium to open a web page using this values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your example code and it works fine. It looks like you just forgot to actually print the value in the final line. That is:

```
data["screen"][0]["id"]
```

should be

```
pprint(data["screen"][0]["id"])
```

which prints `u'1'` when I try it.

Comment: also: `data.get("screen")[0]["id"]`

Comment: Yes, that would work too. But the elements are accessible as an ordinary array as well.

Comment: How would I print all the values in from one section and without the u'? Thanks

Comment: Use for loops. :) The u is because it is in unicode, see documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Of course thats the unicode so its doesn't matter when I use it so for printing I could use print data["screen"][1]["user"] and for counting the amount of json values I have I can just use print len (data['screen'])

Comment: I do have another question if you could put me in the right direction so for the values I would like to put them into a url like example.com/test/page.php?=[screen][1]["code"] if that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the best way would be to convert into an array-like string to be honest.